# How to pass additional intent values to a ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

I simply try to pass an additional value through an ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent and I can't manage it. I need to show the tree dialog, so the user can select a folder and I have to pass some additional info. I already used this passing mechanism with other intents and fear that this doesn't work for the special intent ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE ?!

I start the intent and pass the value simplevalue as follow:
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

```
                  String sOperations="simplevalue";
                  intent.putExtra("simplevalue", sOperations);
                  startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
```

I try to receive the simplevalue as follow:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    // if (requestCode == REQUEST_QUICKLIST) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode==42){

            String simplevalue="";
            simplevalue=data.getStringExtra("simplevalue"); // <-- is null

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); // <- is null
            if(extras == null) {
                simplevalue= null;
            } else {
                simplevalue= extras.getString("simplevalue");
            }
```

the simplevalue and the bundle extras are null when debugging.
Howto pass a simple string with the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE Intent ?

Comment: have you achieved it yet?

Comment: No. The solution went in another direction.

Comment: Ok. I think that the intent we pass to the startActivityForResult is not the same one which invokes the onActivityResult. Therefore it doesn't contains the values you specified.

Comment: Any hint on how you did? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't use thes Tree function. It was not usable for me, because I had to stream data from the internet to that writable space.

Answer (score 1):

On another class you can get simplevalue using,

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String simplevalue = intent.getStringExtra("simplevalue");
```

Comment: I don't understand ? As you can see in my code I already use the getStringExtra and the returned value is null. Can you describe more detaild what you mean with another class ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the intent we pass to the startActivityForResult is not the same one which invokes the onActivityResult. Therefore it doesn't contains the values you specified.

I think we can manage it using an intermediate activity which accepts and stores your values passed through the intent and start the intent 
 `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);`
There onActivityResult you can put the stored values the result intent and provide it as your intermediate activities result.

Answer (score 0):

Late entry, but perhaps it will be useful. To bypass intents, and still access your `simplevalue` in your `onActivityResult`, I'd suggest keeping a dictionary (possibly persisted, it's up to you) of them in your activity, keyed by request code. For example, in:

```
Map<int, String> map = new HashMap<int, String>();
int nextOpenDocTreeCode = 43800;
```

Cycle your request codes in some range (e.g. 43800-43899), where you fire the intent, and put it in the map:

```
map.put(nextOpenDocTreeCode++, "type of animal");
nextOpenDocTreeCode = (nextOpenDocTreeCode >= 43900) ? 43800 : nextOpenDocTreeCode;
```

Then in your `onActivityResult`, retrieve it:

```
simplevalue = map.get(requestCode);
```